# Volley or Retrofit for Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, retrofit, android-volley

Can I use `Volley` or Retrofit` for **Firestore** database? If it possible, how to do that, if not what can I use instead of Volley or Retrofit, and how to use that for achieving data faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use Volley or Retrofit for Firestore database?

The short answer is no. Both Volley and Retrofit libraries are helpful when you want to retrieve a JSON data structure from a REST-based web service, as both provide a relatively easy mechanism for that. Since Cloud Firestore doesn't offer such an option, as [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) does, you cannot use Volley nor Retrofit. However, if you want, you can use RxJava or RXAndroid for that.

If you are asking for an advice for how you should build your app, I can only advise you to check the official documentation regarding on how to [get started with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).

One thing to note is that the mechanism that is provided does **not** help you get the data in a JSON format. If you need that, you should get the data according to the docs and then write some code for that. In that way, you can create a JSON object out of that.